# Setting up Raid 1 Array for Home Server

Tags: backup, raid, windows-server-2008, home-server, redundancy

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but it's worth asking on here! Essentially I have a old machine at home (well, not old hardware wise, but I recently built a new gaming rig), which I decided to install a copy of W2008 R2 on and use as a file/backup server and media center'ish machine.

As of now, it has a single drive partitioned into C and D, with D being the Data partition. I have happened to find an old 1TB SATA drive lying around at home, and was wondering if it's possible to setup a Raid 1 array in my rig within Windows without needing to lose everything on my first drive (or maybe even just mirror a specific partition, say the Data partition, as this is just what stores my photos etc). Maybe this isn't possible, but you never know :)

Regards,

T.C

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm no massive Windows wizard, having been a dedicated Linux user for a few years, but I remember that the program `mmc.exe` was able to create RAID arrays under XP. If you run `mmc` from the Start Search menu, and hit `Ctrl-M` to add "Disk Management", you should be able to create a new RAID partition. The downside is that, as I remember, you'll have to delete the partition that you wish to RAIDify, so finding some temporary backup space is probably a good idea. I believe the program refers to the RAID1 as "Mirrored" instead of RAID1, but you hopefully can find it rather easily.

Good luck!